# Making mouseenter/mouseleave functions for many elements less repetitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

I have a bunch of buttons on the page that will trigger a specific corresponding image to appear under the group of buttons (only 1 image will be displayed on the page at a time). Is there a way to make the code more DRY?

```
// Toggle donation icons on hover
$('#donate-btn1').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-50').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-50').hide();
});

$('#donate-btn2').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-100').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-100').hide();
});

$('#donate-btn3').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-200').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-200').hide();
});

$('#donate-btn4').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-400').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-400').hide();
});

$('#donate-btn5').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-750').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-750').hide();
});

$('#donate-btn6').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-1000').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.icon-donate-1000').hide();
});
```

Comment: try getting some common class to those elements and then use that to select and apply using this

Comment: Are you aware that after calling `.hide()` on element you will never get any mouse event on it, ever?

Comment: @Frax but it's not the element that will be hidden that have the mouse event, it's the button

Comment: @CalvinNunes Right, fair point.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: A sidenote: Depending on the DOM structure, if the icon can be made to be a child or sibling of the button, it may be also possible to produce a CSS-only solution, which would be a bit simpler and more performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it DRY if you use a `class` instead of an `id` and also take advantage of html data attributes, something like this:

```js
    $('.donateButton')
    .on('mouseenter', function() 
    {
        let icon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
        $('.icon-donate-' + icon).fadeIn();
    })
    .on('mouseleave', function() 
    {
        let icon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
        $('.icon-donate-' + icon).hide();
    });
```

```css
.icon-donate-50, .icon-donate-100{
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="donateButton" data-icon="50">Donate 50</button>
<button class="donateButton" data-icon="100">Donate 100</button>

<span class='icon-donate-50'>50</span>
<span class='icon-donate-100'>100</span>
```

Comment: Dude, thank you! Works like a charm. Great solution.

Comment: Glad to help mate. Thanks @Calvin for adding the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer to the accepted one:

If using an ID is non-negotiable or you're not allowed to change/create classes, for hysterical raisins, you can also use attribute selectors on the id and class properties:

```
$('button[id^="donate-btn"]').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
    $('[class*="icon-donate"]').fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('[class*="icon-donate"]').hide();
});
```

I still recommend using classes whenever possible, but this has been the case for me in certain circumstances.